# jq to fetch value using key from a nested json when a key can be deeply nested

Tags: sh, jq

I have a nested JSON as shown below. I need to list down the values of all  '.url' no matter how deeply it is nested.

```
{
 section1: {
  url: "abc/efg/dgh.com",
  name: "test1"
 },
 section2: {
   .section3: {
     url: "efef/dedede/efdgh.com",
     name: "test2"
    }
 }
}
```

The expected output is as follows:

```
["abc/efg/dgh.com", "efef/dedede/efdgh.com"]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If you need to access something "no matter how deeply it is nested", then `recurse` is your friend.

```
jq '[recurse|.url? // empty]' file.json
```

The question mark prevents us from failing when the recursion reaches something that is not an object (eg. the leaf strings). And `//empty` replaces the nulls we get from objects without an "url" key with empty results (so it deletes them).

Comment: Thanks Michal, i have zero knowledge in shell scripting. i tried to execute the code  u sent in jqplay(https://jqplay.org/) with the above mentioned JSON, but it didn't seems to help.

Comment: Interesting. The jq version on jqplay requires space between `?` and `//`, the version on my computer does not.